# Select text between specific columns in everyline of the output

Tags: android, bash, output, cut

I have a output something like :

```
xxxxxxxxxFOOxxxxxxxxxxxx
blablabl BAR lablblablaa
=========tst============
```

what can i do for have something like :

```
FOO
BAR
tst
```

Which command should i use for only display text between specific column in all line?

`cut -d` will not work cause its not the same delimiter in every lines ..

**PS :** Its on android and few command missed ..

thx for helping ...

Comment: string length is fixed?

Comment: @susemi99 Almost ... But let say yes ..its like only 5/6 lines more longer in a + 1000 lines output ..

Comment: do you know how to use substring()?

Comment: a little.. sould i use a loop for that or can i do directly for all the output without ? @susemi99

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `cut -d` will not work cause its not the same delimiter in every lines ..

Yes but `cut -c10-12` does the job, extracting only the 10th, 11th and 12th character of each line. You don’t provide examples of longer lines, so it is not clear what you want to do in that case.

Comment: That exactly what i was looking for .. longer lines is not any more prob, what i need is always on same place from the beggin of the line  .. @dario Thx you .

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] str = {"xxxxxxxxxFOOxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "blablabl BAR lablblablaa",
                "=========tst============"};

for (String s : str) {
  int half = s.length() / 2;
  String cutted = s.substring(half - 3, half);
  // or String cutted = s.substring(9, 12);
  // => FOO, BAR, tst
}
```

Comment: I asked for bash .. Your code looks like java , is it ?

Comment: sorry. because android tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple method like this:

```
private static String selectBetween(String input, int numberOfCharacters) {
    int startIndex = (input.length() - numberOfCharacters) / 2;
    return input.substring(startIndex, startIndex + numberOfCharacters);
}
```

And then you just call this: `String output = selectBetween("123123ABC123123", 3);// output will be ABC`

Comment: I asked for bash ? Your answer looks like java .. is it ?